# Two-parameters Wiener process

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-theory, brownian-motion

Two-parameters Wiener process $W(r, u), r \in [0, 1], u \in [0,1]$ is a stochastic process with a covariate kernel $\mathbb{E}\left[W(r_1, u_1) W(r_2, u_2)\right] = \min(r_1, r_2) \min(u_1, u_2)$.

How can I find sample path/sheet for this process?

Comment: What do you mean by "hind" (or "find"?) a sample path? Do you want to simulate the process...?

Comment: Sorry for misprint, I mean "find". Yes, I want to simulate this process

Comment: The covariance you suggest seems to imply that $W$ can be constructed as $W(r,u)=B_1(r)B_2(u)$ for two independent linear Brownian motions $B_1$ and $B_2$.